# Is it possible to notify/warn that current path isn't a valid symlink anymore?

Tags: bash, symlink

Let's say we have `./a` and `./b` directories. Then we create a symlink using `ln -s a x` and entering it `cd x` The `pwd` would be `x`

Then in another terminal we change the `x` so that it pointed to `b`. But the first one would still return `x` for `pwd` which is not consistent anymore.

So is there a way for current terminal (bash) to alert/warn if the current path is the obsolete symlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach which uses the fact that bash does command expansion on `$PS1` to test to see if `.` and `$PWD` have the same inode in the prompt:

```
PS1='$([[ $(stat -Lc%i $PWD 2>/dev/null) == $(stat -c%i .) ]] || echo "\[\e[1;31m\]PWD invalid or changed \[\e[m\]")'"$PS1"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any way to accomplish this with just regular Bash. You could setup `inotify` so that it would watch a given directory and then notify the user, typically through email, but there are likely ways to pipe these messages back into a user's shell/environment.

But these notifications would be broad in the sense that they would just come to the users when the links were changed/broken, they wouldn't be contextual, i.e. they wouldn't be sent only when the user was actual in these said directories.

#### Example

Terminal #1:

```
$ mkdir $HOME/tst
$ inotifywait -mr $HOME/tst
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
```

Terminal #2:

```
$ mkdir somedir
```

Terminal #1:

```
/home/saml/tst/ CREATE,ISDIR somedir
/home/saml/tst/ OPEN,ISDIR somedir
/home/saml/tst/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR somedir
```

Terminal #2:

```
$ rmdir somedir
```

Terminal #1:

```
/home/saml/tst/ DELETE,ISDIR somedir
/home/saml/tst/somedir/ DELETE_SELF
```